# Android ListView and EditTexts with live data

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext, android-arrayadapter

I have a simple ListView backed by my ArrayAdapter which is being updated every ~5 seconds or so with new data. Every 5 seconds, I'm invoking notifyDataSetChanged on my ArrayAdapter which results in the ListView getting redrawn with the new data. All this works fine and I'm seeing new data every 5 seconds.

However, in the getView method of my ArrayAdapter, I'm inflating a LinearLayout which includes an EditText. Here's the problem I'm trying to address:

1. User has selected the EditText in one of the rows and types in some input.
2. User stays focused on the EditText for more than 5 seconds.
3. notifyDataSetChanged gets invoked as new data has arrived in my array adapter.
4. User loses focus on the EditText as it has been redrawn. notifyDataSetChanged seems to result in all ListView elements getting redrawn.

What's the best way of allowing the user to maintain focus on this EditText but ensure that the data is always fresh?

Thanks,

Sean

Comment: Write custom `BaseAdapter` that provides actual (available in memory, not null) views, selected one (like which user selected and typing the text or focused for the moment). To update data: store a list of objects that describes your data in the adapter, then go throw the list and if view is available, update it manually (like in `getView` method) with associated (new) object. It's kind of imitating `notifyDataSetChanged`

Comment: Hi Vladimir - thanks for the response. I should have really outlined this in my original question, but I'd prefer to continue using notifyDataSetChanged if at all possible. Going through each row in the ListView and updating views instead of relying on getView being called is not a road I'd want to go down immediately. As the number of items in my data set can change, I'm not sure the list view iteration solution is viable for me. Thanks all the same.

Comment: No problem, you can play around these methods http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getFirstVisiblePosition%28%29 and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.html#getLastVisiblePosition%28%29

Answer (score 0):

it may not be the best way but a fast way. overwrite notifydatasetchanged, first check if you have a element that has the focus (or store it when it gains focus and not lose it), store the input, call super.notifyDatasetChanged, write the old value.

if the adapter has too many items, this may not be a good solution.

Comment: Siyamed - thanks for your comment. Would you mind expanding a little on why this solution wouldn't be a good idea if my adapter has 'too many' items?